# How to use function to connect to database and how to work with queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection, user-defined-functions

I am using functions to work with database.. Now the way i have defined the functions are as follows:-

```
/**
 * Database definations
 */
define ('db_type', 'MYSQL');
define ('db_host', 'localhost');
define ('db_port', '3306');
define ('db_name', 'database');
define ('db_user', 'root');
define ('db_pass', 'password');
define ('db_table_prefix', '');
```

---

```
/**
 * Database Connect
  */
function db_connect($host = db_host, $port = db_port, $username = db_user, $password = db_pass, $database = db_name) {
    if(!$db = @mysql_connect($host.':'.$port, $username, $password)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if((strlen($database) > 0) AND (!@mysql_select_db($database, $db))) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    // set the correct charset encoding
    mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER_SET \'utf8\'');
    return $db;
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Database Close
  */
function db_close($identifier) {
    return mysql_close($identifier);
}
```

---

```
    /**
 * Database Query
  */
function db_query($query, $identifier) {
    return mysql_query($query, $identifier);
}
```

Now i want to know whether it is a good way to do this or not.....

Also, while database connect i am using

```
$host = db_host
```

Is it ok? Secondly how i can use these functions, these all code is in my **FUNCTIONS.php** The Database Definitions and also the Database Connect... will it do the needful for me...

Using these functions how will i be able to connect to database and using the query function... how will i able to execute a query?

---

**VERY IMPORTANT**: How can i make mysql to mysqli, is it can be done by just adding an '***i***' to mysql....Like:-

```
@mysql_connect
```

---

```
@mysqli_connect
```

Comment: Re mysql -> mysqli: Best look at the examples in the manual.

Comment: Pekka - OOps it is @mysqli_connect

Comment: Try using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @AbhilashShukla, what questions do you have? Do you mean that you wrote the above functions and you do not know how to use them? Weird!

Comment: @Abhay i know that my question, i have defined some constants... as my database connection datas... now in the very next function i am using those constants in my function... i have never done that... so asking.. hope u'll help :)

Comment: Here are some tutorials that might help: [(1)](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) and [(2)](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

Comment: @tereško thanks for the info... will go through it as have not been through PDO..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With global constants, you can directly use them inside a function. So in this case,

```
/**
 * Database Connect
 */
function db_connect() {
    if(!$db = @mysql_connect(db_host . ':' . db_port, db_user, db_pass)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if((strlen(db_name) > 0) AND (!@mysql_select_db(db_name, $db))) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    // set the correct charset encoding
    mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER_SET \'utf8\'');
    return $db;
}
```

And here is how you can implement the client code:

```
<?php
if(!$conn = db_connect()) {
    die('cant connect to mysql');
}
$rs = db_query('SELECT * FROM tableA', $conn);
/* loop through the resultset */
db_close ($conn);
?>
```

Regarding converting mysql to mysqli, no it might not be that straight-forward; just adding an "i" might not work. MySQLi has different syntaxes. For one, the port is explicitly passed to the connect method rather than appended to the host as done above. Please read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

You should also consider using PDO library as suggested by Simone Vittori.

Comment: can you also tell me will i can make `@mysql` to `@mysqli`... unable to find it in php manual...

Comment: Of course you can make mysql to mysqli but the transition might not be that straight-forward. Also I will suggest using the object style of MySQLi rather than procedural style. I've given a link in my response

Comment: The `@` (stfu operators) are not necessary.  Checking the length of the DB name is a rather uncommon check.  Setting the DB name can be done in the initial connection call.